# Linear elasticity governing equation

Tags: solid-mechanics

Transient linear elasticity is governed by the following hyperbolic PDE:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2(\rho \boldsymbol{u})}{\partial t^2} - \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{\sigma} = \boldsymbol{F}
\end{align}

This equation is hyperbolic and has no dampening term, so it will never dampen and won't reach equilibrium, i.e., it doesn't have a steady state form. If this equation doesn't have a steady state form, then why is the following equation frequently referred to as the steady state (or equilibrium) equations? 
\begin{align}
- \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{\sigma} = \boldsymbol{F}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equations that you've written are statements of conservation of momentum.  The elastic wave equation is derived by applying Newton's second law to a continuum (and usually assuming small strains).  This leads to a linear response relation connecting the stress and strain tensors via the fourth-rank tensor of elastic moduli.  But, if I understand, I think your question can be reformulated very simply.  The scalar wave equation $$c^2 \nabla ^2 u = \frac{\partial ^2u }{\partial t^2}$$ can be used to illustrate the point.  There are two ways of inserting attenuation into this.  The first is to add a small complex term to c (in the Fourier domain).  Or in the elastic case make the moduli complex (in the Fourier domain).  The other is to postulate some mechanism for the attenuation.  Perhaps it's adding a velocity dependent term to the wave equation.  Or in electrodynamics, the presence of a current (plus Ohm's law) will give you first as well as second partial derivatives with respect to time of the E and B fields.  So instead of a pure wave equation, you get something like a telegraph equation; the result is damped oscillatory solutions.  But fundamentally it's no different than a harmonic oscillator.  Without a damping term it will oscillate forever.  Hooke's law alone is not enough.  Does that help?

Comment: Yes, I understand that a damping term (proportional to velocity) could be added to achieved damped oscillatory solutions. In this case, there would be a steady state solution at infinite time if the damping term was to be added. But I think my question deals more with the semantics of why people refer to the $\nabla \cdot u = F$ equation as the "steady state" (or "equilibrium") equation, when the transient equation NEVER reaches steady state, absent of damping?

Comment: Without reading the full text you're referring to, my guess is that a) attenuation has been sneaked in somehow (such as making c complex (in Fourier domain), or b) we ignore the damping to make the solution easier, but then naively ask what happens at hypothetical equilibrium.  I.e., just set the time derivatives equal to zero.  But as you point out in the OP, this is inconsistent.  You can never really ignore attenuation (except for EM waves in vacuum) since it violates causality (Kramers Kronig).

Comment: There's a lot of conference and journal papers that seem to refer to it as the "equilibrium" or "steady state" equations. I can link you to some later if you would like. I have also found many links on Google that refer to them as the same. Such as Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_elasticity#Elastostatics

Comment: @user27504, in the Wikipedia article the acceleration is zero. The solutions are time independent then (except for rigid body motions).